# LCDS or blazeds or flex default timeouts for channels or application

Tags: apache-flex, timeout, default, blazeds, lcds

I am working on lcds application and am using secure-amf channel for remote object calls.
Calling Websphere server(Java EE application).

I want to know the timeouts associated with the channels or timeouts in application.
Is there any documentation for the timeouts of a channel. I read configuration document in dev guide.

(RemoteObject requestTimeout whats the default value ??)
?

I mainly want to know.. default values for
connection timeout, request timeout, AsyncTimeout and if possible other timeout values

Does LCDS/Blazeds have option to  configure these or accepts default server values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time-out of connection is actually set by Http server, default 5 mins, whatever that of AMF channel is set.

Answer (score 1):

The default timeout for an AMF Channel is 0 which means there is no timeout. The relevant property is 'idle-timeout-minutes'. See the second table in this web page: 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=lcconfig_3.html